# data.table grouping by column names from a variable sets column names as "get"

Tags: r, data.table

I need to aggregate a data table by columns given as strings in variables. I'm using `get` to achieve this but the column names in the resulting table are named as "get" instead of the original names. How to avoid this?

```
dt = data.table(id = rep(LETTERS[1:4], 1, each = 3),
                grp = round(runif(12)),
                val = runif(12))

col.names = names(dt)

dt[, .(meanByIDByGrp = mean(val)), by = .(get(col.names[1]), get(col.names[2]))]

   get get    meanByIDByGrp
1:   A   1 0.5628882
2:   A   0 0.6021001
3:   B   1 0.4013824
4:   B   0 0.0551370
5:   C   1 0.6031302
6:   C   0 0.7107527
7:   D   1 0.2778507
```

Comment: Try `by = .(name1 = get(col.names[1]), name 2 = ...)`. The `.()` is just a shortcut to `list()` which allows names in this way.

Comment: Yes, that works if I set the name explicitly but not if I do `by = .(col.names[1] = get(col.names[1]))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dt[, .(meanByIDByGrp = mean(val)), by = col.names[1:2]]
# id grp meanByIDByGrp
# 1:  A   1     0.1638516
# 2:  A   0     0.5859206
# 3:  B   1     0.4907845
# 4:  B   0     0.3665976
# 5:  C   1     0.6644277
# 6:  D   0     0.5028973
```

Comment: Wow, that simple... Tried different `eval` forms except the simplest. Thanks!